# Starting and stopping Spring Boot metrics on demand

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, metrics, micrometer

Spring Boot 2.x here. Reading through [metrics/micrometer docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) and trying to figure out how I could stop/restart all metrics collections on the fly at runtime.

It looks like the typical way metrics registries are created are:

```
SimpleMeterRegistry registry = new SimpleMeterRegistry();
```

And I would expect this to happen in a `@Bean`-annotated method from inside a `@Configuration`-annotated class. So to me, this indicates that the registry is started automatically as part of some background process. However, for my application, I want to be able to explicitly start/stop/restart metrics collection on demand.

**Any ideas as to how to accomplish this?** Thanks in advance.